# How do you use a local variable in a bash function?

Tags: bash, sh, alias

I have a test list of all the Cards Against Humanity white cards. My goal is to type in rancard and get a random card's string back from the caghw.txt file. So if 212 is the random number, then line 212 is printed. This is what I have in my .bashrc:

```
rancard ()
{
    card=echo $((1 + RANDOM % 706))

    #I'm trying to take the random value returned from
    #the math function above and use it as an argument
    #to the head command

    head -$card /root/caghw.txt | tail -1
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I know I have the general idea right but am not too familiar with the syntax.

As a disclaimer, this isn't for school or anything. It's for my own amusement.

Comment: That is not a local variable. `bash` has local variables (`help local`) but `sh` might not.

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
card=$((1 + RANDOM % 706))
```

here we are saving the output of arithmetic expansion, `$((1 + RANDOM % 706))` in variable `card`. Do the same if you ever want to save the output of command substitution, `$()`.

Your one would work if you wrap the command with command substitution, `$()`:

```
card=$(echo $((1 + RANDOM % 706)))
```

which is absolutely unnecessary, and redundant as saving the output of arithmetic expansion would do as shown above.

---

So your function can take the following final form:

```
rancard () {
    card=$((1 + RANDOM % 706))
    head -"$card" /root/caghw.txt | tail -1
}
```

or if you want to make the variable `card` local, use the `local` keyword:

```
rancard () {
    local card=$((1 + RANDOM % 706))
    head -"$card" /root/caghw.txt | tail -1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Next to the answer already given, I would optimize your function in order to remove the `head` and `tail` command by just using `sed`:

```
sed -n "$((1 + RANDOM % 706))p" /root/caghw.txt
```

`-n` is to remove the automatic line printing done by default by `sed`.
The `p` is saying to print the line number calculated by `$((...))`